# One month behind date show in angular 4

Tags: datepicker, asp.net-web-api2, primeng, angular4-forms

**One month behind date show in angular 4**

**Primeng Calendar Add `2018-04-30` & show `{3/30/2018}`**

**Html File:**

```
<div class="col-md-8 noPadding">
        <p-calendar dataType="date" name="PublishDate" [ngModelOptions]="{utc: 
            'true'}" [ngModel]="resource.PublishDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" 
            (ngModelChange)="resource.PublishDate = $event" showOtherMonths="true" 
            dateFormat="yy-mm-dd" [showIcon]="true"></p-calendar>
</div>
```

**Typescript:**

```
update() {
                this.loading = true;
                this.publishDate  = this.resource.PublishDate.getMonth() + '-' + this.resource.PublishDate.getDate() + '-' + this.resource.PublishDate.getFullYear();

               this.resource.PublishDate = this.publishDate
                let data = JSON.stringify(this.resource); 


                this.resourceService.putForm('Resource').subscribe((response: any) => {
                    detail: 'Resource is Updated' });
                }, (error: any) => {

                });
            }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a moment to review the tour: [stackoverflow.com/tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), *How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*: [stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and *How to Ask Good Questions* [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - you'll get better feedback and helpful answers if you put some thought in to your problem before coming to SO for help, and by including a specific problem with code that you've tried showing effort to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: my problem is solved by using datepipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ts:**

```
this.publishDate = this.datePipe.transform(this.resource.PublishDate);
```

**html:**

```
<p-calendar dataType="date" name="PublishDate" [ngModelOptions]="{utc: 
    'true'}" [ngModel]="resource.PublishDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'"
       (ngModelChange)="resource.PublishDate = $event" showOtherMonths="true"
          dateFormat="yy-mm-dd" [showIcon]="true">
</p-calendar>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
providers: [
    DatePipe
]
```

by using angular date pipe my problem is resolved
thankyou
https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe